# Retrieve Applications Requests (apprequests) through FQL?

Tags: facebook-graph-api, request, facebook-fql, fql.multiquery

From the Requests Dialog [document](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/dialogs/requests/):

> **Graph API**
>   To retrieve a single User ID from a single Request ID using the Graph API, issue an HTTP GET request to the `request_id`:
>   `https://graph.facebook.com/[request_id]?access_token=USER_ACCESS_TOKEN`

Is this request available through FQL?

Answer (score 0):

Yes this is available via the [apprequest fql table](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/fql/apprequest/):

```
SELECT request_id, app_id, recipient_uid, sender_uid 
FROM apprequest 
WHERE request_id = 10150308414012941
```